# Imageview not loading at all

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the viewcontroller.h I am doing this.

```
@property( nonatomic, strong)IBOutlet UIImageView*showLogo;
```

In the viewcontroller.m I am doing this.

```
   NSString*path=@"http://www.stboston.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/iStock_000004791880_1.jpg";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data ];

 _showLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500)];
     _showLogo.image=img;
```

Comment: are you adding the UIImageView to the current view?

Comment: [self.view addSubview:_showLogo];

Comment: yes adding the UIImageview to currentview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try loading it directly into the _showLogo.image

```
_showLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500)];
_showLogo.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:@"http://www.stboston.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/iStock_000004791880_1.jpg"];
[self.view addSubview:_showLogo];
```

or

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stboston.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/iStock_000004791880_1.jpg"]];
_showLogo.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
[self.view addSubview:_showLogo];
```

Comment: That's great answer, I totally forgot about adding it back in the view